# Facebook SDK Initialization

Tags: android, xml, facebook, authentication, firebase

Actually I'm trying to do user login with facebook in my android application with firebase auth... 
When On create method call 
at this stage 
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)` code through exception for this button

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton>
 android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>
```

In new facebook sdk the FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()) has been deprecated so I don't need to initialize facebbok sdk anymore but when i run the app at that moment I'm getting following errors..

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
```

Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.

and I'm using following dependency

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

Comment: `<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton>` why `>` here .Remove `>`

Answer (score 0):

**change it your layout file**

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggest call this line of code FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() before setting the content view.You can do it in you application class . Say

```
class YourApplication extends Application{
   onCreate(){
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()
}
}
```

Make sure to provide the name of your application in android manifest application's tag

```
<application 
name="YourApplication">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sdkInitialize` method was deprecated in version 4.19.0. I suggest you use the latest version of the sdk which is

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
```